# Memory Allocation C

Tags: c, memory, pointers, free

I have a memory allocation question.  If I declare a `char*` within an `else` block that means the `char*` is destroyed when the `else` block is done executing.  The `else` block is located in a `while` loop so it will iterate many times.  However, what if the `char*` declared in the `else` block is aliased to a `malloc'd` variable as seen in the below example.  My question is how do I fee something like this?  I feel as though if I free the temp `char*` variable, I will cause a segmentation fault because I will free the variable I want to keep as well.  If that is the case, I'm at a loss for where the `free` statement goes.

```
char* print_path = NULL;
```

(snip)

```
  (while)

 else{
        char* temp_path = print_path;
        int temp_size = strlen(temp_path)+strlen(file_name(child->fts_path))+1;
        print_path = (char*)malloc(temp_size);
        strcpy(print_path, temp_path);
        strncat(print_path, file_name(child->fts_path), strlen(file_name(child->fts_path)));
        printf("%s:\n\n", print_path);
        }
```

(snip)

I would like to point out that I do free print_path at the end of the program after I know it will not be executed again.  However, it is the intermediary executions of the loop that I would like to free.  Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You are confusing things that are stack allocated and heap allocated.  You are not freeing the pointer, you're freeing the memory that the pointer points to.

Comment: What's the point of freeing during every iteration of the loop? You know you're going to need that segment of memory for the duration of the loop, freeing and reallocating doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: @JordanKaye The point of freeing during every iteration is because the previous iteration's dynamically allocated variable is no longer needed.  If this is run over a long enough data sample, there will be no memory left.  It is also good programing practice to free all malloc'd variables when they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `free(temp_path)` is the right thing. It should go like this:

```
char * print_path = malloc(...);    // "NULL" is also possible

while (condition)
{
    if (...)
    {
         // ...
    }
    else
    {
        char * temp_path = print_path;

        print_path = malloc(...);

        free(temp_path);
    }
}

free(print_path);
```

The invariant in your algorithm is (or should be) that `print_path` always points to dynamically mallo­cated memory. Note how we have precisely one `free` for every `malloc`.

Comment: yes, that is where i originally had the `free(temp_path)` statement however I am getting a segmentation fault but I thought that I might have been doing something wrong with it because I was almost positive that the `free` was supposed to go there.  Could it be that the temp_path is not actually a dynamically allocated block of memory?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 pointers:

`print_paths`: Points to an array like `['h','e','l','l','o']`, this pointer contains the address for the first element of the array, in this case it points to `h`, lets say that the address of this `h` is `1`, so, the address of `e` is `2` and so on... hence, `print_path` contains the number `1`.

`temp_path`: this pointer points to nothing or to a random place in the memory.

When you call `malloc`, `malloc` ask for some memory and gives you the address of the new allocated memory, but this memory contains garbage.

So after

```
print_path = (char*)malloc(temp_size);
```

`print_path` contains the address of the new allocated memory, a new array of size `temp_size` which has garbage, lets say that this address is 40, so the value of `print_path` is `40`.

finally, when you call:

```
strcpy(print_path, temp_path);
```

you copy the values of the array `temp_path` (`['h','e','l','l','o']`) to the array pointed by `print_path`, in other words, the address `40` instead of containing garbage now contains `h`, `41` contains `e` and so on.

It's important to note that, even if both address (`1` and `40`) contains the value `h`, modifying one doesn't affect the other.

The best place for the `free(temp_path)` is just before the end of the `else`, just check that `temp_path` is allocated memory, if you try to free memory that it wasn't obtained with `malloc` your'e gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Thank you, but that I had tried that before I posted because I had a segmentation fault when I put it there.  Could it be that it is because `temp_path` is a copy of `print_path` instead of dynamically allocated?

Comment: @tpar44 maybe is because your first `print_path` is `NULL`, are you trying to free a `NULL` pointer?, try something like this
`if (temp_path!=NULL)
       free(temp_path);`
if your first `print_path` is not a `NULL` pointer, probably you are assigning to `temp_path` something like `temp_path=child->fts_path`, i.e. you are assigning to `temp_path` memory that you are gonna use later, so, you free it in this part of the code, and you try to access it later

Answer (score 0):

I believe that since, the gist of what I want to do is reallocate memory to the same variable, I should have looked into realloc instead of malloc.